# Initial balance (Visit Visa)

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, serial-refusals

My visa application has been refused 3 times..The first refusal was about cash deposit, spnosor family ties evidence and plan of stay...Second refusal was about cash deposit...The third refusal about initial balance and not provide strong family ties back in home country. However I have already provide, marriage certificate, child birth certificate, land indenture, and car documents. I did indicate in my application I am a freelancer and I used my highest earning as my monthly earning.

I intent traveling to the UK for military assessment event. The recruiter has given me a green light to contact him when I get the visa..
[image]
Please advice

Comment: “I want to join the Army in the UK” clearly signals that whatever ties you may have in your country, you are willing to leave all of that behind you. Also you should have an invitation letter from the Army, but they “_are no longer inviting applications from Commonwealth nationals who have not resided in the UK for more than 5 years_” so the reason for your visit does not seem consistent with the current situation, is it?

Comment: I have been invited and I am in continous contact with the recruiter....

Comment: @MorganDeen Did you apply through the official British Army website? What advice has the recruiter given regarding serial refusals? *The recruiter has given me a green light to contact him when I get the visa* sounds like a generic response, I imagine the British Army issues 000s of ‘invitations’ and many of them won’t proceed because the applicant can’t get a visa.

Comment: I was asked to send email of my visa confirmation to him and we will discuss further...that was through email conversation..